# Spring security login page gives 404

Tags: spring, security

I am new to spring security, I am getting a http 404 when I try to access the login page which is a jsp page. I am using

1. Tomcat 7
2. Spring framework 3.1.1

Here is the tomcat Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Initializes log4j -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>formVilleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>formVilleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the spring root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/resources/"/>

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->    
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
   <beans:property name="basename" value="views"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xtremesoftwaresolutions.formville" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You maps Spring MVC Servlet to handle all requests when you do following:

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

So, when you trying to get access to your JSP page, like `/login.jsp` then Spring MVC catch it and try to find appropriate controller and action which will manage it. So, probably simplest way is to create controller which just return JSP page as is. I suggest to try something like this:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login.jsp" view-name="/login.jsp" />
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you find my answer useful, you may accept it.

Comment: Suspect that implementation details have changed since this was posted: trying this on a current version gives a 500 response with exception "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError"